# Compilation error on file lib/phoenix/token.ex: Phoenix.Socket.__struct__/0 is undefined

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When running a fresh setup with Docker Compose, we see this error on compilation:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/phoenix/token.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/phoenix/token.ex:144: Phoenix.Socket.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct Phoenix.Socket
   (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
could not compile dependency :phoenix, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile phoenix", update it with "mix deps.update phoenix" or clean it with "mix deps.clean phoenix"
```

I'm not sure why. Looking into the `/deps/phoenix/lib/phoenix/token.ex` and `/socket.ex` gives no indication as to why this might be happening.

This is with Elixir 1.3.2 and Phoenix 1.2.0.

Comment: You mention that you are running the phoenix application inside Docker. Are you by any chance using the same application folder that you use in development via a Docker mount (as in `docker -v "$PWD":/app ...`)? If that's the case, it might be that Phoenix is using the pre-built artifacts from the `./build` folder, which were compiled in a different platform.

Comment: @PotiguarFaga we're using Docker Compose so our `docker-compose.yml` does use the same application folder. It's possible that you're right, that the end user is doing both normal compiling on their host machine and then also trying to use via Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Since you confirmed that there your `docker-compose.yml` mounts the application folder inside the docker container, I will elaborate a bit further on how I solved some compilation issues I was having in a similar scenario. This does not address the specific error you are asking about but it might serve as guidance for finding out a more adequate answer to your problem.

I develop on a Mac OS/X and use a docker debian-based image to build my Phoenix Framework projects. I mount the application folder inside the container via `docker -v "$PWD":/app -w /app potz/elixir-build mix phoenix.server` (`potz/elixir-build` is just a custom image I use with some stuff pre-installed). This presents a problem because when Phoenix runs inside the container it sees the `_build` directory with pre- compiled artifacts and tries to use that, but of course this throws out all kinds of weird compilation error messages since they were built in a different platform (OS/X). Also, dependencies are saved in the `./deps` folder and those were also pre-compiled on OS/X.

My solution to the problem is to instruct docker to use different folders for both the build artifacts and dependencies, effectively separating the two environments while still using the same application source files. In order to do that I need to allow the `build_path` and `deps_path` settings in `mix.exs` to be overridden by environment variables:

```
def project do
  [app: :my_app,
   version: "0.0.1",
   elixir: "~> 1.3",
   elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
   compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
   build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
   build_path: System.get_env("BUILD_PATH") || "_build",  # Allows different path for builds
   deps_path: System.get_env("DEPS_PATH") || "deps",      # Allows different path for deps
   start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
   aliases: aliases(),
   deps: deps()]
end
```

Then when running on docker I provide these two values as environment variables, e.g.:

```
# /build and /deps can be folders inside the container,
# or mounted volumes, whatever makes sense to your specific setup
docker run -v "$PWD":/app -w /app -e BUILD_PATH=/build -e DEPS_PATH=/deps potz/elixir-build mix phoenix.server
```

Of course I have a custom shell script to avoid remembering this huge command-line all the time, but I'm guessing you can adapt to your Docker compose setup. You just need to make sure you have those folders created inside the container first, or remember to mount two extra volumes on those paths, whatever makes more sense.

I hope this helps.